# How can I print the first text inside a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a soup object like:

```
<span class="nowrap">
     2 633
    <span class="currency rub">q</span>
</span>
```

I did:

```
price = item.find('span', class_='nowrap')
price_x = price.text.strip()
print(price_x)
```

Result: 2 633 q.

How can I get without 'q'. Just: 2 633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `.text` gives you all the strings inside the tag concatenated. You should use `next_element` instead:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<span class="nowrap">
     2 633
    <span class="currency rub">q</span>
</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('span', class_='nowrap')
next_element = price.next_element
print(repr(next_element.strip()))
```

output:

```
'2 633'
```